# Is aov F Estimate Legitimate for Unordered Factors in R?

Tags: r, anova, categorical-data

Unordered factors are basically dealt with in R by dummy coding them to compare the base level of the factor to every other level.

Thus, I understand why asking for a summary on a regression of a continuous variable predicted by an unordered factor shows each level of the factor (except the base level, which each level is being compared to).

```
example<-cbind.data.frame(rnorm(100), rep(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),20))
names(example)<-c("y", "A")
summary(lm(y~A, data=example))
```

However, when I use the aov function to analyze the same unordered factor, I just get an F estimate for the overall effect of the factor.

```
summary(aov(y~A, data=example))
```

Is this F estimate legitimate, or should I report the t estimates from the individual comparisons?

Comment: The F estimate is correct.  But note that it is calculated with Type I sum of squares.  For routine use, I recommend using `Anova` in the `car` package which uses Type II sum of squares by default.  It doesn't matter in this case, but it can matter in more complex designs, particularly with an unbalanced design.

Comment: `example<-cbind.data.frame(rnorm(100), rep(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),20)); names(example)<-c("y", "A"); model = lm(y~A, data=example); if(!require(car)){install.packages("car")}; library(car); Anova(model)`